# Word that describes experiencing something second-hand

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, vocabulary

What word describes experiencing something second-hand?

This word has been on my mind a long time, but it keeps eluding me. 
The word, I think it's an adjective, describes experiencing something second-hand. It could be used to describe, for example, gossiping or reading a book - the listener/reader experiences second-hand what he/she hears/reads.

It probably starts with 'i' or 'v'!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You might be thinking of **[vicarious](http://:%20experienced%20or%20felt%20by%20watching,%20hearing%20about,%20or%20reading%20about%20someone%20else%20rather%20than%20by%20doing%20something%20yourself)**; in particular:

> - "felt or enjoyed through imagined participation in the experience of others".

(M-W)

Comment: Possibly also 'by proxy'. `Stan experienced the skydive through his best friend and proxy Lee, whom he knew would tell him all about the free fall in great detail.`